# vertical align icon with text center issue Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have problems with center. I want to center icon and text on the same line with Bootstrap but its not working good. I am beginner here so I dont know much. Wanted this: Example https://i.stack.imgur.com/prSlD.png

```
My code what i have tried:


 <section class="container-fluid bg-dark text-center">
    <h2>WHY US</h2>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
      <img class=" me-3" src="img/icon.png"style="width:40px" alt="">
      <h5 class="mb-0">FAST DELIVERY  </h5>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , I think this will work

```html
<section class='container-fluid text-center'>
    <h2>WHY US</h2>
    <div class='d-flex align-items-center w-100 justify-content-center'>
      <img
        class='me-3'
        src='img/icon.png'
        style='width:40px'
        alt=''
      />
      <h5 class='mb-0'>FAST DELIVERY </h5>
    </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: That isnt working, still not centered

Comment: If you add another one its on the same line.I wanted something like at the example picture.

Comment: If you can try the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
        <h2>WHY US ?</h2>
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center gap-2">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i>
            <h5 class="mb-0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ,consectetur</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center gap-2">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i>
            <h5 class="mb-0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ,consectetur</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center gap-2">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i>
            <h5 class="mb-0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ,consectetur</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center gap-2">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i>
            <h5 class="mb-0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ,consectetur</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have use font awesome icon you can replace it with your image tag.Hope that work for you :)